# Spring cloud data flow server cloud foundry config server

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I deployed spring cloud data flow server cloud foundry to PCF (with cf push SPRING_CLOUD_DATA_FLOW_SERVER_CLOUD_FOUNDRY JAR).When i run it it try to connect to http://localhost:8888 as a config server.

I'm using my own config sever and in manifest file i'am using services: config-service (as a user provided service).But even with this config it will try to connect http://localhost:8888.

This is my manifest file:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Could you edit the post and include the `manifes.yml` in entirety, please? Also, if you can share the SCDF-server bootstrap logs, that'd help also.

Comment: I answered by adding the manifest file. I already bind the server to my config server.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that you haven't bound your Config server service `config-service` to the SCDF cf server. You can either edit your SCDF server manifest YAML to add `config-service` into `services` or do the binding explicitly as `cf bind-service <scdf-cf-server> <config-service>`.

Comment: I answered by adding the manifest file. I already bind the server to my config server.

Comment: How do you setup your config server service? Is it git based and do you enable specific profile? If so, you need to have `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` set for the SCDF server with the corresponding profle.

Comment: Yes both Config server and SCDF is set to git profil in the manifest file

Comment: how can i override spring.cloud.config.uri  to be able to use the property from manifest instead of bootstrap.yml.